# Add clicks when differents div are clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Im working on a project and i have basically some troubles with things for my website.
This one is  a bit hard for me, i have some ideas but i dont know how to do them in my javascript code.
I have 98 divs (it's a calendar where you can select everyday differents hours to book slots).
There is a Summary (kinda same thing on commercial website) which i want that it says how many slots you selected. But the problem is that i have like I said 98div so i wanna do it in one function.
On the slots you want to book, you can click on it (it selects it) and if you click on it again it deselects it.
I want that you can select as many slots that you want, and the summary shows how many you selected then you can go to next step.
Here is my code if you guys have some ideas !

```
function x1(e) {
var target = e.target,
count = +target.dataset.count;


 target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#707070" : 'black';  
 target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;
 target.innerHTML = count === 1 ? '' : 'réserver';
 target.classList.toggle('Resatxt');
 target.classList.toggle('unselectable');
 
 }
```

Actually this code is for the selection of the slots (it's going background black when you clicl on it, and then back to the normal color when you deselect it).
But i think i can do what i want with this.
I thinked about incrementing +1 when we click on the div but the problem that i dont know how to figure it out is when you deselect it you have to do -1 but im a bit lost.

I tried to be clear but ik that is not really.
If you guys have some ideas, go for it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are there any issues with the code above? I see you have some sort of boolean behaviour to change the background-color, which seems to be fine. You don't necessarily need to increment or decrement it, tracking a 1/0 or a boolean (true/false) should do the job

Comment: Thanks for your return man, and no, there is no issues on the code above, everything is working well, but i was asking for ideas to do what i wanna do, how can you do what you said ? So i can try it myself :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

it's nice to see that your joining the programming community. I hope I understood you correctly and made a simple and minimal example to present you how can you achieve what you want. This is just an idea, don't take it too serious and write your own logic to handle the functionality!

```js
const divs = 98;
const list = document.querySelector("#list");
const selectedList = document.querySelector("#selectedList");
let selected = [];
let elementsAdded = 1;

const onSelectDiv = (element) => {
  const elementCopy = element.cloneNode(true);
  elementCopy.id += "-copy";

  selected = [
    ...selected,
    {
      id: elementsAdded,
      elementId: element.id
    }
  ];

  elementsAdded += 1;
  selectedList.appendChild(elementCopy);
};

const onClick = (e) => {
  if (e.target.className.includes("selected")) {
    e.target.classList.remove("selected");
    elementsAdded -= 1;

    const elementToDelete = selected.findIndex(
      (x) => e.target.id === x.elementId
    );
    
    selectedList.removeChild(selectedList.childNodes[elementToDelete + 1]);

    selected = selected.filter((x) => x.elementId !== e.target.id);
    return;
  }

  onSelectDiv(e.target);
  e.target.className += " selected";
};

for (let i = 0; i < divs; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML += i;
  div.className += "div";
  div.id = i;
  div.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    onClick(event);
  });

  list.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: 'column';
}
#list {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.div {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
<div>
  <p>Elements:</p>
  <div id="list">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Selected:</p>
  <div id="selectedList">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks a lot for this answer, it's going to help me. But actually to be more precise, my divs are in a grid and they have each one ID, how can i /should i use your code, im coding in javascript everyday for 2 month now and im understanding 90% of your code, but i have a lot of things to learn ! That's why im a bit confuse everytime.

Comment: The whole point of my code is to present how can you achieve such type of functionality. You'll have to use true/false as someone mentioned before or you can store selected elements ID in an array as I did in the example. My example is based on ID, if you click on a div, I save clicked div ID in an array and later on remove it once the element is  deselected. You just have to decide whats best for your application, we don't know the whole structure.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your return, im trying it since 2 day but i cant because your code use a list, and actually my 98divs are in a grid. Im trying a lot of things, but it's hard. I have 98 divs so 98 ids, and i dont want to repeat 98 times the code. By the way, the id's of my div's are like : "x1", "x2"..."x97", "x98". Cant i just do something with 'x+n' or ? Thank you